# Google Map price in real time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

There are 100 active vehicles that I want to track. If I update the position every 5 seconds is a lot? I'm confused with the calculations to estimate the price of using Dynamic Maps that is updated in real time.

A quick calculation:

100 active vehicles that work 8 hours a day for 20 days in the month sending coordinates every 5 seconds

```
 (60/5 seg)*60*8*20*100 = 11520000 Map Loads
```

Considering the price table
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/
Is it too expensive to use google maps for a tracking system?

Comment: map load happens when you execute `new google.maps.Map()`. I think your estimation of map loads is wrong.

Comment: Hello!, hmm Maybe I'm wrong. I thought map loads happended when a marker was updated on the map.. So I can have an open map (new google.maps.Map()) and be listening to the marks updates without having to pay google every 5 seconds?

Comment: You can find explanation regarding map loads in Google maps platform documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Maps JavaScript API's [Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps) is only billed per map load or per map display.

One (1) map load is counted every time a map is created by instantiating the `google.maps.Map()` class. Displaying multiple markers/pins or only updating the marker coordinates in the map will **not** add to the map load count unless you call the google.maps.Map() class for each update.

Hope this helps!